# I have State and City List to display horizontally whereas the display is not even

Tags: css, html-lists

I am trying to display state wise cities horizontally whereas so far i am not able to display them evenly. Enclosed please find the screenshot of current way of display.

Below is the code i am using for display States and Cities. Please help me in understanding where i am going wrong.
Please find provided below the link for screenshot for your reference:

[image]

```
<ul>State1
<li>City1<li>
<li>City2<li>
<li>City3<li>
<li>City4<li>
<li>City5<li>
</ul>
<ul>State2
<li>City1<li>
<li>City2<li>
<li>City3<li>
<li>City4<li>
<li>City5<li>
</ul>
<ul>State3
<li>City1<li>
<li>City2<li>
<li>City3<li>
<li>City4<li>
<li>City5<li>
</ul>
etc....!
CSS:
ul{
width:25%;
float:left;color:#ABCDEF;
}
```

Comment: Your last column doesn't look 25% width to me. Can you provide the website link or full code example? I feel like something else is interfering

Comment: I had attached a portion of the list in the image. The issue is the 1st  line is getting distributed evenly.(Please refer to Alabama, Alaska, Alberta & Arizona). State Arkansas is supposed to come down at the bottom of state Alabama which is not happening because the list and heights are different for each UL. This is the issue i am facing. Also there is nothing much i have added to css. I had mentioned the same which i am using. Data is being displayed from database. I just added float to ul with width:25%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`column-count` css might be an escape here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.newspaper {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the column-count property.</p>

<div class="newspaper">
<ul>
<li>ABJHDGD</li>
<li>ABJHDGD</li>
<li>ABJHDGD</li>
<li>ABJHDGD</li>
<li>ABJHDGD</li>
<li>ABJHDGD</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>BJHDGD</li>
<li>BJHDGD</li>
<li>BJHDGD</li>
<li>BJHDGD</li>
<li>BJHDGD</li>
<li>BJHDGD</li>
<li>BJHDGD</li>
<li>BJHDGD</li>
<li>BJHDGD</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>JHDGD</li>
<li>JHDGD</li>
<li>JHDGD</li>
<li>JHDGD</li>
<li>JHDGD</li>
<li>JHDGD</li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works for me although not perfect, But seems there is no option lect. Only few of the cities are being listed on the other column without heading. But then thats ok. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use flexbox instead of floating. This will make all the lists even height and wrap properly but you need a container around the ul's:

**HTML**

```
<div class="list-container">
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.list-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.list-container ul {
    width: 25%;
}
```

Check out full codepen example: http://codepen.io/StefanBobrowski/pen/KWjNoG

Comment: I have used what you mentioned. Now all the states and cities are displaying in 1 single column.

Comment: Works for me, checkout the codepen link i edited into the answer

Comment: Technically you are right. But the li count from state to state is of huge difference. For example: State Alabama has 5 cities whereas California has 90Cities :-(. So wherever the list is huge is it leaving huge space in between. Hope you understand my issue.

Comment: Oh you want a masonry layout as seen here: http://thenewcode.com/844/Easy-Masonry-Layout-With-Flexbox     Check out my updated codepen

Comment: Yep. I am looking for masonry Layout. for UL and LI. :-)

Comment: Yes this works fine. Thats what i am looking for. Thanks Stefan. Accepting answer. :-)